# Can you display upvote count near the comments posted under Profile section?

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, comment-voting

I want to track how close I am to getting the ***[Pundit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit)*** badge but I just don't seem to find a way.

> Leave 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

While I am able to see all the comments posted under my [Profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/150645/biscuitboy?tab=activity&sort=comments) (all actions -> comments), I am unable to see the upvotes (if any) received for my comments.

Was this feature skipped due to any reasons? Will you please consider showing the comment upvotes next to the comments (in the area marked shoddily with a Snipping Tool in the below screen shot)? If possible, an option to sort by comment upvotes too, please!

[image]

*Note*: Please do not redirect me to an SEDE script.

The duplicate question is 5 years old! And no indication if the request was even considered.

Comment: That question is 5 years old. And no indication if the request was even considered. Any useful updates @Shadow Wizard?

Comment: just one of many feature requests that will probably never get even a hint of official attention, but still duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - That's sad. I will delete the question then. I am sure the brilliant minds behind this site sure have a justification to ignore a pertinent request that has been upvoted more than 50 times. Thanks!

Comment: Lack of time and too few developers are two reasons. :)

Comment: @Justin, if you have nothing useful to add to a post or some important reason to edit it (like a tag burnination) it's better not edit it, there is no use for this to be on peoples question feed.

Comment: @Justin I see what you edited, hence my comment. There is no need to do such minor edits on ancient questions. If the posts becomes relevant for whatever reason, a dupe target perhaps, then by all means feel free. Otherwise keep ancient stuff ancient, please, especially if the only edit you have is useless one.